# Finding two major peaks and the valleys between the peaks of a 2D array or histogram

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, image-processing

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<c[i].length;j++)
    {
         if(peak1[i]<c[i][j]){
         peak1[i] = c[i][j];
         peak1loc1[i]= j;
     }
}     


 println(peak1[2]);
 println(peak2[2]);`
```

Here is what I have tried so far. For some reason `peak1` and `peak2` are printing the same values.

I have a 2-dimensional array that holds RGB color values of an image. I want to find two major peaks of each channel (r,g,b), and the valley between these two major peaks, so I will get two major peaks for red, two major peaks for green, two major peaks for blue and a valley (the smallest value between the major peaks), so three valleys in total.

Is there any algorithm for this or can anyone give me some ideas how I can find these? A pseudocode would be really helpful.

Comment: What have you tried?  And it seems like "2 major peaks and the valley in between" would mean you're talking about a 1-d array.  How are you wanting to deal with the 2nd dimension?

Comment: for example the array  will be like this int[0]={1,2,3,4,..256}

Comment: Your code won't compile, for several obvious reasons.  What have you really tried?  With your example, what answer would you expect?  Is there one array for red, one for green and one for blue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
import java.util.*;
color[][]  c = new color [10][2];


void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c[0].length; j++) {
      c[i][j] = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    }
  }

  float[] reds = new float[c.length*c[0].length];

  for (int i = 0; i < reds.length; i++) {
    if ( i < c.length)
      reds[i] = red(c[i][0]);
    else
      reds[i]=red(c[i-c.length][1]);
  }
  println("\n unsorted red values");
  println(reds);
  Arrays.sort(reds);
  println("\nSORTED");
  println(reds);

  println("\n\n the bigger red value is: " + reds[reds.length-1]); 
  println("\n the 2nd bigger red value is: " + reds[reds.length-2]); 
  println("\n the smaller red value is: " + reds[0]); 
  println("\n\n cheers");
}
```